# updating a text with additional characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, character

I have the following value format :

**1234567890**

I want to convert it to the following format : **123-45A67890**

Table Name: Test

Column Name : MyCode

Note that I am using Microsoft SQL 2012.

Comment: Do you want to UPDATE existing table data, or do you just want to modify SELECT returned data?

Comment: what do you mean by `text`... `varchar` variable or `varchar` column?

Comment: I want to update the data because it  already have the value filled. The column is nvarchar(255) type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` . Something like this

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(15) = '1234567890'

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@v,4,0,'-'),7,0,'A')
```

Your `SELECT` would be

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(MyCode,4,0,'-'),7,0,'A')
 FROM Test
```

Your `UPDATE` would be

```
UPDATE Test
SET MyCode = STUFF(STUFF(MyCode,4,0,'-'),7,0,'A')
```

Comment: I used the latest one for update and it worked but how can I do this for many values.

Comment: The `UPDATE` is a `SET` based operation. It will update `MyCode` for all the rows in your table unless you specify a filter

Answer (score 0):

Does SQL Server support the `PASTE` function?

```
paste(paste('1234567890',7,0,'A'),4,0,'-')
```

For example:

```
select paste(paste(column_name,7,0,'A'),4,0,'-') from table_name
```

or

```
update table_name set column_name = paste(paste(column_name,7,0,'A'),4,0,'-')
```

Comment: what is `paste`? plz explain or give helpful link!

Comment: your `paste` function looks very close to `STUFF` which is available in SQL Server

Comment: PASTE is another non ANSI SQL string handling function, apparently not supported by SQL Server. As ughai mentions, it seems to be pretty much the same as SQL Server's STUFF function.

Answer (score 0):

Here what tried with a variable `@a`:

```
declare @a varchar(100)='1234567890'

select STUFF(STUFF(@a,4,0,'-'),7,0,'A') --gives--> '123-45A67890'
```

Likely you can use it to update your table, which

> 1. Adds Hyphen (-) after first 3rd character,
> 2. Adds letter 'A' after 2 letters just after hyphen...

```
update Test set MyCode = STUFF(STUFF(MyCode,7,0,'A'),4,0,'-')
```

More about [STUFF() function in SQL](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=3934817c-1a03-4ac9-a0ba-55b2bfbaea0f&tkw=uses-of-the-stuff-string-function)